# Displaying progress indicator while loading external objects in global.R

Tags: r, shiny, reactive-programming

## Background

I've a simple app that loads number of files when launched in `global.R` the code to load data files looks as follows:

```
lst_dta <- lapply(X = seq_along(vec_dta_fls),
                                   function(i) {
                                       incProgress(
                                           amount = 1 / length(vec_dta_fls),
                                           message = paste("Reading file:", vec_dta_fls[i])
                                       )
                                       readr::read_rds(vec_dta_fls[i])
```

where `vec_dta_fls` contains file paths  of the files to source.

## Problem

I would like to encapsulate this process within [`withProgress`](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/progress.html) call to provide dynamic information on progress.

### Code

```
withProgress(message = "Reading data files:",

             expr = {
                 lst_dta <- lapply(X = seq_along(vec_dta_fls),
                                   function(i) {
                                       incProgress(
                                           amount = 1 / length(vec_dta_fls),
                                           message = paste("Reading file:", vec_dta_fls[i])
                                       )
                                       readr::read_rds(vec_dta_fls[i])
                                   })
             })
```

### Error message

> Error in `withProgress(message = "Reading data files:", expr = {` :
>   `'session'` is not a ShinySession object.

## Notes

I understand that this is because I'm calling `withProgress` within reactive context, as suggested in the [linked article](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/progress.html):

> The simplest way to add a progress indicator is to put withProgress()
>   inside of the reactive(), observer(), or renderXx()

Is there a way I can work around? For this particular case, I don't want to call `withProgress` within reactive context as, in effect, I only want to display this loading message once.

Answer (score 1):

I guess this would do the trick

**server.R**

```
library(shiny)
shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {

    load_data()

    output$title_loaded_from_global <- renderUI({
        strong(title_ui)
    })

    output$my_summary <- renderPrint({
        summary(data1)
    })

})
```

**ui.R**

```
library(shiny)
shinyUI(fluidPage(
    uiOutput("title_loaded_from_global")
    ,verbatimTextOutput("my_summary")
))
```

**global.R**

```
load_data <- function() {
    withProgress(message = 'Load data and title...', value = 0.5, {
        # Load data
        Sys.sleep(2)
        data1 <<- iris
        title_ui <<- "A great iris summary"
    })
}
```

Comment: Well there is a catch here; creating objects in `global.R` makes them accessible in `ui.R` as well as `server.R`. If II do what you suggested I will have to run this functionn in `ui.R`; `wiithProgress` takes `session` argument is there no way to find it and pass to the *progress* function?

Comment: You're right ! The only one solution I found is to use `renderUI` from the server side. I updated my answer

Comment: Thanks very much for your contribution, I will leave it hanging day or two to see if no one contributes a solution using session ID. I may  be mistaken, but in my view it should be possible to get this thing to work by taking app session ID and forcing it as an argument to `withProgress`. I reckon that [`session`](https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/1.0.0/session.html) object *should have* the relevant info. I reckon it's not far off from using `ns <- session$ns` as discussed [here](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/modules.html). It's just not obvious for me how to do this.